# Kickstart PXE Boot Installation not working

Tags: linux, redhat, pxe-boot, kickstart

I tried installing PXE Boot Installation Server on RHEL 6.0. I seem to have done everything according to the page: http://www.linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/pxeboot.html.

In my case, the client boots, gets DHCP IP address from our server, connects to the Kickstart server too, but then nothing happens. It shows:
Loading 192.168.1.101: pxe.linux.0 .....

192.168.1.101 in my kickstart server.

Did any one face such a situation?

I'm using a test env on Oracle Virtualbox with DNS Server on RHEL 6.0, DHCP Server on CentOS 6.0 and Kickstart server on RHEL 6.0.

The image I'm trying to install is that of REHL 6.0!

Awaiting some responses!

Cheers,
Anshuman

Comment: What's in the logs on the server? In particular, are there any messages about tftp? Do you have a tftp server running? Can you try downloading the file directly from the server using tftp?

Comment: Logs say nothing unusual. DHCP Server shows the IP request and IP allocation. The Kickstart Server has no entries pertaining remote installation!!!

Comment: How about connecting to the server with tftp on the command-line?

Comment: Have you verified firewall is not blocking TFTP ports? It sounds like it is stuck at the initial TFTP process of grabbing the pxelinux.0 loader.